# Preview App bug - "Highlight" shortcut not working normally

Tags: keyboard, pdf, high-sierra, preview, highlights

I'm not able to use "Highlight" shortcut. No matter I press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, it results in underlining text. Clicking the "Highlight" button also underlines text. I can highlight text using highlight with specific though.

But it's quite inconvenient that I am not able to use shortcut to highlight. How could I fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try clicking the highlight button (while not having any text highlighted) and select the highlight colour. It'll show a check mark beside the one you choose. Then unclick it and try the highlight shortcut again and it should make the default that colour highlight.

Answer (score 2):

I just find you can select no text then change default highlight type. So it's not a bug and problem solved.

Comment: Nice workaround but still a bug.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to use any shortcut command ... its direct... just keep the highlight selected and u can highlight text by just double finger drag...

[image]